# prevent symbolic link follow from git repo HOWTO

Tags: git, version-control, vc, symbolic-links

I have git repo here: ~/git/myrepo/

then I do:

```
ln -s ~/external_dir ~/git/myrepo
```

emacs follows symbolic link when opening the file: ~/git/myrepo/external_dir/somefile.txt

I'd like to prevent it, ideally on a per git repo (dir-locals) basis

following doesn't bring the desired effect:

```
(setq vc-follow-symlinks nil)
```

also:

```
(setq vc-follow-symlinks 'ask)
```

does not make emacs ask a question when opening a file.

I'm running emacs.28.2

please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of `vc-follow-symlinks`.

In the situation you described, Emacs doesn't ask anything because the version controlled file `~/git/myrepo/external_dir`, which is a symbolic link, is not edited. The file that is edited is `~/external_dir/somefile.txt` and is not under version control as long as `~/external_dir` is not a Git repository.

By setting `vc-follow-symlinks` to `'ask`, Emacs will prompt you if the **target** of a symbolic link is under version control.

Example :

```
ln -s ~/git/myrepo/someotherfile.txt ~/external_dir/someotherlink
```

`~/git/myrepo/someotherfile.txt`, the target of the symbolic link `~/external_dir/someotherlink` is under version control. Now if you invoke *e.g.* `find-file ~/external_dir/someotherlink`, Emacs will prompt you (still assuming `vc-follow-symlinks` is set to `'ask`).

Comment: ok, I understand.

Comment: Then, what should I do for emacs not to resolve link from my question?  I mean, when I'm in shell and do `cd ~/git/myrepo/external_dir`, then `pwd` tells it's in `/home/user/git/myrepo/external_dir`. I'd like emacs behave the same way.

Comment: If you invoke find-file `~/git/myrepo/external_dir` you will end up in a Dired buffer where the directory name is `/home/user/git/myrepo/external_dir`. Emacs does behave the same way as the shell. At the end, I don't know how to prevent Emacs from resolving the symbolic link in your situation.

Comment: Tristan, thank you for your time and explanation. I'll have dig deeper to understand what's going on my site